# Error in Oauth2 process: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: sonos

I've been having a bit of trouble with receiving a code from the Sonos API for my application to then get a token for later API requests, specifically the error above. Is there any sort of test code or option to temporarily skip Oauth2 to test the API requests I already have written? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of the GET requests you're making, and detail a little the environment in which you're making the call?

Answer (score 0):

If there was that would be a bit of a gigantic security hole. Just fix your auth code.